# Vue submit form data with PHPMailer

Tags: javascript, php, vue.js, phpmailer

I'm trying to submit a contact form from a page, but when the form is submitted, nothing happens.  I'm using Vue, Axios and PHPMailer for this.
**In the network tab I can see that actually the post.php file couldn't be found. But it exists and it's located in the root of the project. Therefore, the path "../post.php" should be right.**
I changed the emails and server data for this question, but all emails exist and are correctly included. Any help is deeply appreciated.
Thanks.

contact.vue

```
    export default {
        name: 'Contact',
        data() {
            return {
                text: '',
                form: {
                    email: '',
                    name: '',
                    telefon: '',
                    checked: [],
                },

                show: true,
            };
        },
        methods: {
            onSubmit() {
                const config = {
                    responseType: 'text',
                };
                
                axios
                    .post(
                        '../post.php',
                        {
                            name: this.form.name,
                            email: this.form.email,
                            telefon: this.form.telefon,
                            message: this.text,
                            checked: this.form.checked,
                        },
                        config,
                    )
                    .then(response => {
                        console.log('success', response.data.message);
                    })
                    .catch(error => {
                        console.log(error.response);
                    });
            },
            
        },
    };
```

post.php

```
    <?php
    
    // Import PHPMailer classes into the global namespace
    // These must be at the top of your script, not inside a function
    use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
    use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;
    
    // Load Composer's autoloader
    require 'vendor/autoload.php';
    
    // Instantiation and passing `true` enables exceptions
    $mail = new PHPMailer(true);
    
    try {
       //Server settings
       $mail->SMTPDebug = 0; // 0 - Disable Debugging, 2 - Responses received from the server
       $mail->isSMTP(); // Set mailer to use SMTP
       $mail->Host = 'smtp.page.com'; // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
       $mail->SMTPAuth = true; // Enable SMTP authentication
       $mail->Username = 'page@page.com'; // SMTP username
       $mail->Password = 'mypassword'; // SMTP password
       $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';//PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_STARTTLS; Enable TLS encryption, `PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_SMTPS` also accepted
       $mail->Port = 587; // TCP port to connect to
    
       //Recipients
       $mail->setFrom('from@email.com', 'Contact Form');
       $mail->addAddress('recipient@recipient.com', 'Recipient'); // Add a recipient
    
       // Content
        $inputJSON = file_get_contents('php://input');
        $input = json_decode($inputJSON, TRUE);
        $name = $input['name'];
        $email = $input['email'];
        $tel = $input['tel'];
    
        $result['message']  = 'test';
    
       $mail->isHTML(true); // Set email format to HTML
       $mail->Subject = 'subject';
       $mail->Body    = $result;
       // Attachement 
       $mail->send();
       echo 'Message has been sent';
    } catch (Exception $e) {
       echo "Message could not be sent. Mailer Error: {$mail->ErrorInfo}";
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried to check the PHP logs?

Comment: I'm suspicious of the `../post.php` path. This path is relative to the current working directory, not the location of the file, so you may find it's not looking in the right place. That should be evident in your web server logs though, where you should see a request with a path in, and then it failing to find a file at a path – and that will tell you where it's actually looking.

Comment: That's right @Synchro. I changed to "/post.php" and the file was found. Now I get success in console but I don't receive any email  :/

Answer (score 0):

So, apparently the issue was the relative path. Removing the '.' solved the issue of the post.php file not being found. I also found out that my emails are not arriving due to CORS issues. I still have no clue how to fix that. I added a .htaccess file to my FTP server, but it's not helping. **Anyway, the issue posted here was solved**.